# pycharm debug report an error, but code is correct

Tags: python, pycharm

Below is the question, and it's been answered. The question is silly and i apologise for asking such trivial question on this site. And no more down-grading pls

---

New to python. I believe the code is correct, so why did the debug report this problem?

[please click the link to see the picture!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQ1hH.png)

Comment: Debugger clearly shows error, read it and find it. Indentation Error: expected an indented block

Comment: thanks. as a newbie I apologise for this @dkb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line 3, there is a "while", so line 4 must be indented.
Line 4 and 5 are not correctly written either.

Pycharm may be wrong sometimes, but rarely. As a beginner, you should first verify your code before thinking the tool is wrong.

Comment: . I don't know in python there's indentation. Thanks. I'll delete this question.

Comment: and as a beginner is pycharm a nice ide to stick to?i mainly use python to do some simple data analysis and charting.

Comment: I definitely love pycharm.

pycharm has advantages and drawbacks for a beginner. The advantage is that everything is integrated. The drawbacks: it has many features, and it can be difficult to learn how to use it.

Alternative: use a multi-purpose code editor (visual studio code, sublime text editor ...). But take the necessary time to configure it with efficient python plugins.